# how to work with the library pingback-php of tedeh

Tags: php, trackback, pingback

Docs Down http://pingback.tedeh.net/!

Source: http://github.com/tedeh/pingback-php

3 Files

http://github.com/tedeh/pingback-php/blob/master/Pingback/Exception.php

http://github.com/tedeh/pingback-php/blob/master/Pingback/Server.php

http://github.com/tedeh/pingback-php/blob/master/Pingback/Utility.php

Please how I can work with this library and Examples

Answer (score 1):

A quick google shows a fork of pingback.tedeh.net at http://github.com/frw/PHP-Pingback - there's a readme with detailed documentation.

Comment: I need an examples, PHP-Pingback is a Fork

Comment: It looks like you're stuck then, unless you can be bothered to read through the code and learn it.

Comment: I do not understand how to implement and I read the code, so wondering if anyone could help me

Comment: You have a 0% answer rate on several questions, which is the lowest I've seen.  No one is going to answer you on anything lol.